# Drawer screens not showing up in react native app when I use drawercontent

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer, react-navigation-drawer

I've been trying a few different things to make this work but so far no luck.
I'm trying to add an image to the top of my DrawerNavigator, and it works when I add it to drawer content, but then the screens are no longer present. When I remove the drawercontent then the screens come back.

Here is my sample code for the drawer navigator:

```
 return (
            <NavigationContainer>
                <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Login" 
                    drawerContent={(props) => <DrawerContent {...props} />}>
                    <Drawer.Screen name="Login" component={LoginComponentScreen} />
                    <Drawer.Screen name="Register" component={RegisterComponentScreen} />
                </Drawer.Navigator>
            </NavigationContainer>
        )
```

And this is the sample code for my DrawerContent:

```
return (\<MenuLogo />)
```

I've also tried adding the Drawer.Screen elements inside the DrawerContent component but no luck there either.

Any help is appreciated.